# Retriving image from firebase into recycler view in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to retrive image from firebase Database (the image is in storage ) .
I'm unable to convert it into url to pass it to picasso to load it in a recycler view . It works if uploaded and retrieved from same device but the image isn't shown on other devices . Any help would be of almost use .
I am trying to store and retrieve image by using Firebase. It is okay when storing an image, but I can't show it in an ImageView. It doesn't give an error so I can't understand where is the mistake.
i gave the required permissions.

Thank you in advnace.
Mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.blogger;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class blogupload extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mBlogList;
    private DatabaseReference mDataBase;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter;
    
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Blog> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Blog>()
                        .setQuery(mDataBase,Blog.class)
                        .build();

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            public BlogViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.blog_row, parent, false);

                return new BlogViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(BlogViewHolder holder, int position, Blog model) {
                holder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                holder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
                holder.setImage(model.getImage());
            }


        };
        adapter.startListening();
        mBlogList.setAdapter(adapter);




    }
    public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View mView;
        public BlogViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView=itemView;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title)
        {
            TextView post_title ;
            post_title=(TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
            post_title.setText(title);

        }

        public void setDesc(String desc)
        {
            TextView post_desc ;
            post_desc=(TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_desc);
            post_desc.setText(desc);

        }

        public void setImage(String image)
        {
            ImageView post_image;
            post_image=(ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);

            Picasso.get().load(image).into(post_image);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_menu,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_blogupload);

        mDataBase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("blog");

        mBlogList=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.blog_list);
        mBlogList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.add:
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), addpostactivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            case R.id.logout:
                mAuth.signOut();
                Intent intent1 =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
}
```

image upload activity

```
package com.example.blogger;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.Random;

public class addpostactivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    private static final int MAX_LENGTH = 23 ;
    ProgressBar mProgress;
    ImageView selectimage;
    TextView posttitle,postdesc;
    Button submitbtn;
    private Uri uri;
    private static final int GALLERY_INTENT=2;
    private StorageReference mStorage;
    private DatabaseReference mDataBase;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode==GALLERY_INTENT&&resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {
            uri=data.getData();
            Picasso.get().load(uri).into(selectimage);

        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_addpostactivity);

        selectimage=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.selectimage);
        posttitle=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.posttitle);
        postdesc=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.postdesc);
        submitbtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.submitbtn);

        mProgress= new ProgressBar(this);

        mDataBase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("blog");


        submitbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startposting();


                
            }
        });
        
        
        selectimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mStorage= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        selectimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("image/w");
                startActivityForResult(intent,GALLERY_INTENT);
            }
        });




    }
    public static String random() {
        Random generator = new Random();
        StringBuilder randomStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int randomLength = generator.nextInt(MAX_LENGTH);
        char tempChar;
        for (int i = 0; i < randomLength; i++){
            tempChar = (char) (generator.nextInt(96) + 32);
            randomStringBuilder.append(tempChar);
        }
        return randomStringBuilder.toString();
    }

    private void startposting() 
    {

        mProgress.setProgress(0);
        mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        String title_value=posttitle.getText().toString().trim();
        String desc_value=postdesc.getText().toString().trim();
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(title_value)  &&  !TextUtils.isEmpty(desc_value)  &&  uri!=null)
        {
            StorageReference filepath=mStorage.child("blog_image").child(random());
            //adding a picture to storage

            filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });


        }

        DatabaseReference newPost=mDataBase.push();
        //newPost.child("uid").setValue(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        newPost.child("title").setValue(title_value);
        newPost.child("desc").setValue(desc_value);
        newPost.child("image").setValue(uri.toString());

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), blogupload.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you able to open image url in browser ?? just print url using System.out.println(image); if it is not open in browser means something wrong with your image url.

Comment: @TusharLathiya   No

Comment: Without url how it will load ? Are you able to get title and description ?

Comment: @TusharLathiya yes

Comment: I think you need to check firebase respond and need to check image url. If possible share response.

Comment: It is image path. check firebase response you can see there image url like title and description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, the problem is in this part of your code:

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(title_value)  &&  !TextUtils.isEmpty(desc_value)  &&  uri!=null)
{
    StorageReference filepath=mStorage.child("blog_image").child(random());
    //adding a picture to storage

    filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


}

DatabaseReference newPost=mDataBase.push();
//newPost.child("uid").setValue(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
newPost.child("title").setValue(title_value);
newPost.child("desc").setValue(desc_value);
newPost.child("image").setValue(uri.toString());
```

The `uri` that you're passing to `filepath.putFile(uri)` is the path to a local locally on the Android device, that you are uploading to Storage. Then you write that **local** path to the database in `newPost.child("image").setValue(uri.toString())`. But since the path is local to the Android device, it won't work on another device.

You need to instead get the download URL of the **uploaded** file, and write that to the database. Based on the documentation on [uploading a file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#get_a_download_url), that'd be something like:

```
StorageReference filepath=mStorage.child("blog_image").child(random());
filepath.putFile(uri).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {

addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return filepath.getDownloadUrl();
    }
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void OnSuccessListener(@NonNull Uri uri) {
        DatabaseReference newPost=mDataBase.push();
        newPost.child("title").setValue(title_value);
        newPost.child("desc").setValue(desc_value);
        newPost.child("image").setValue(uri.toString());
    }
});
```

Differences to note:

- The code that writes to the database is **inside** the `onSuccess` listener, since that gets called once the image has been uploaded to Storage.
- We now have a call to `getDownloadUrl` to determine the download URL, which is a URL to the file in Cloud Storage that anyone can use to access its data.
- Since `getDownloadUrl` is also an asynchronous call, we have a `continueWith` call to chain the asynchronous tasks. We could also have nested the completion listener, but this is what the documentation did.